# How to add ServletContainerInitializer to Grizzly WebappContext?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, grizzly, servlet-listeners

I create Grizzly WebappContext this way:

```
WebappContext webContext = new WebappContext("WebappContext", "");
```

And I have MyInitializer that implements `ServletContainerInitializer`. How can I add this initializer to webContext? I tried this way:

```
webContext.addListener(new MyInitializer());
```

But `MyInitializer.onStartup` method is never called. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServletContainerInitializer` is based on Service Provider Interface (SPI) concept. Implementation of `ServletContainerInitializer` interface must be configured in `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file.
This `jar` contains a listener must be in `WEB-INF/lib` of a ServletContainer.

`webContext.addListener` will serve your needs but the given listener must be an instance of one or more of the following interfaces:

```
- javax.servlet.ServletContextAttributeListener
- javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener
- javax.servlet.ServletRequestAttributeListener
- javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener
- javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener
```